# How to save wav file after using filter in LabView?

Tags: audio, filter, save, converters, labview

Using structure like this, I'm wondering how to change signal, back to data, to save it after modification. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to wire the output of the Index Array function direct to the input of the Filter vi, and the output of the multiply function direct to the input of the Sound File Write Simple vi. That works for me in LabVIEW 2014.

If you really want to do the conversion explicitly you can convert the dynamic data to an array, build that into a waveform (using the input waveform as a template to preserve the sample rate setting `dt`) and build that into a 1D array:

[image: Modified filter code (draggable LabVIEW VI snippet)]

Comment: Thank You, this is what  I was looking for.